# How can i creat a function to avoid duplicated values. (VBA Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

The problem is: I need to insert some data in a form, this form i can save, edit and delet the data,
but has a specific data that needs to be unique, so that when I insert the value i can't put the same value again.

**I'm tring to put this condition in (txtRG)**

I already tried everything I knew but didn't work, cause when i tried to edit de value,
the same understands that I'm trying to insert the same data again, so this is the code:

```
UserForm1 (Code)


Option Explicit

Private Sub btDeletar_Click()
Dim nLin As Integer

If tgbEditar.Value = True Then
    nLin = ListBox1.ListIndex
    If nLin = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Selecione um item para Deletar"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf ListBox1.Value = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Selecione um item para Deletar"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Call Deletar
    
Else
    MsgBox "Coloque no Modo Edição"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub btSalvar_Click()

Dim nLin As Integer

If tgbEditar.Value = True Then
    nLin = ListBox1.ListIndex

        MsgBox "Selecione um item para editar"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf ListBox1.Value = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Selecione um item para editar"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Call Editar
Else
    Call Inserir
End If

End Sub


Private Sub Image1_BeforeDragOver(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal DragState As MSForms.fmDragState, ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

Dim nLin As Integer
nLin = ListBox1.ListIndex
If nLin = -1 Then Exit Sub

If bloqueado = True Then Exit Sub
If ListBox1.Value = 0 Then
    txtRG.Value = ""
    txtMotorista.Value = ""
    txtPlaca.Value = ""
    txtEmpresa.Value = ""
    txtTransportadora.Value = ""
    txtMateriais.Value = ""
    txtPorteiro.Value = ""
Else

    txtRG.Value = ListBox1.List(nLin, 1)
    txtMotorista.Value = ListBox1.List(nLin, 2)
    txtPlaca.Value = ListBox1.List(nLin, 3)
    txtEmpresa.Value = ListBox1.List(nLin, 4)
    txtTransportadora.Value = ListBox1.List(nLin, 5)
    txtMateriais.Value = ListBox1.List(nLin, 6)
    txtPorteiro.Value = ListBox1.List(nLin, 7)
End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Call Atualizar_ListBox

End Sub
```

```
Modulo1 (Code)


Option Explicit
Global bloqueado As Boolean

Sub Inserir()

bloqueado = True
Dim Tabela As ListObject
Dim n As Integer, id As Integer

Set Tabela = Planilha1.ListObjects(1)
id = Range("ID").Value


n = Tabela.Range.Rows.Count
Tabela.Range(n, 1).Value = id

Tabela.Range(n, 2).Value = UserForm1.txtRG.Value
Tabela.Range(n, 3).Value = UserForm1.txtMotorista.Value
Tabela.Range(n, 4).Value = UserForm1.txtPlaca.Value
Tabela.Range(n, 5).Value = UserForm1.txtEmpresa.Value
Tabela.Range(n, 6).Value = UserForm1.txtTransportadora.Value
Tabela.Range(n, 7).Value = UserForm1.txtMateriais.Value
Tabela.Range(n, 8).Value = UserForm1.txtPorteiro.Value

UserForm1.ListBox1.RowSource = ""
Tabela.ListRows.Add

Range("ID").Value = id + 1


Call Atualizar_ListBox
Call LimparCampos

MsgBox "Cadastrado com sucesso!", vbInformation, "Sucesso"
bloqueado = False

End Sub

Sub Editar()

bloqueado = True
Dim Tabela As ListObject
Dim n As Integer, l As Integer
Set Tabela = Planilha1.ListObjects(1)

n = UserForm1.ListBox1.Value
l = Tabela.Range.Columns().Find(n, , , xlWhole).Row

Tabela.Range(l, 2).Value = UserForm1.txtRG.Value
Tabela.Range(l, 3).Value = UserForm1.txtMotorista.Value
Tabela.Range(l, 4).Value = UserForm1.txtPlaca.Value
Tabela.Range(l, 5).Value = UserForm1.txtEmpresa.Value
Tabela.Range(l, 6).Value = UserForm1.txtTransportadora.Value
Tabela.Range(l, 7).Value = UserForm1.txtMateriais.Value
Tabela.Range(l, 8).Value = UserForm1.txtPorteiro.Value

Call Atualizar_ListBox
Call LimparCampos

MsgBox "Atualizado com sucesso!", vbInformation, "Atualizado"
bloqueado = False

End Sub
Sub Atualizar_ListBox()

bloqueado = True
Dim Tabela As ListObject
Set Tabela = Planilha1.ListObjects(1)


UserForm1.ListBox1.RowSource = Tabela.DataBodyRange.Address(, , , True)

bloqueado = False

End Sub

Sub Deletar()

bloqueado = True
Dim Tabela As ListObject
Dim n As Integer, l As Integer
Set Tabela = Planilha1.ListObjects(1)

n = UserForm1.ListBox1.Value
l = Tabela.Range.Columns(1).Find(n, , , xlWhole).Row

UserForm1.ListBox1.RowSource = ""
Tabela.Range.Rows(l).Delete

Call Atualizar_ListBox
Call LimparCampos

MsgBox "Deletado com sucesso!", vbInformation, "Deletado"
bloqueado = False
End Sub


Sub LimparCampos()

UserForm1.txtRG.Value = ""
UserForm1.txtMotorista.Value = ""
UserForm1.txtPlaca.Value = ""
UserForm1.txtEmpresa.Value = ""
UserForm1.txtTransportadora.Value = ""
UserForm1.txtMateriais.Value = ""
UserForm1.txtPorteiro.Value = ""

End Sub

Sub EXIBIR()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

PS: Sorry for my English, i'm Brazilian.

Comment: Use a `Dictionary` object to store your data. you can use the unique data as the Key and check to see if it exists before adding any new data to the Dictionary. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object

Answer (score 0):

Use Match,

```vb
Sub Inserir()

    bloqueado = True
    Dim Tabela As ListObject
    Dim n As Integer, id As Integer
    
    Set Tabela = Planilha1.ListObjects(1)
    id = Range("ID").Value
    
    Dim isExists
    isExists = Application.Match(UserForm1.txtRG.Value, Tabela.DataBodyRange.Columns(2), 0)
    If Not IsError(isExists) Then
         MsgBox "Already exists"
         Exit Sub
    End If
    ... etc
```